# How to save large data in cookie

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

According to this article [Browser Cookie Limits](http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/) we can store 4kb string in per cookie.

Now i want store more than 4KB string in cookie (no LocalStorage).

What is your solution for this?

---

```
cookie[0] = 4kb
cookie[1] = 4kb
cookie[2] = 4kb
cookie[3] = 4kb
```

This is a good way. But I do not know how to code it.

Comment: laravel has nothing to do with **browser** cookies

Comment: My solution would be **don't** ... use a session instead (not sure why this question was upvoted tbh - seems to hit the very definition under the downvote button *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*).

Comment: My first question is what the hell are you storing that much data in a cookie for?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. We can send cookie as response in laravel .`\Cookie::make("name", "value", 3000);`

Comment: I once put too much chocolate chips in a cookie once, it turned out to be a chocolate bar with a bit of flour in the center. This post reminded me of that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `post_id` that visitor has liked it.

Comment: I know you said "no LocalStorage," but if you realllllllly need to store lots of data that's a good way to do it. Or `SessionStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: I don't see how an `id` can possibly be 4kb of data. If you want to store *all* of the user's liked posts, use a server side data store.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i want save multiple id with `json_encode(array(ids))` as string in cookie and keep data for 30day!

Comment: In which case localStorage or a server side data store is exactly what you need to use.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. seems i should use localStorage!

Comment: back in a days we used `window.name` to extend ie6 cookie limits, but these days it is a bad practice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question (but an awful idea), so I decided to test it out just for fun (and I'll even give you teh codez so you can do it if you insist).. But the problem is cookies are sent to the server with every request from that domain, and if you cram as much arbitrary data as you can into your cookies pretty soon the request headers will be too big for the server to understand..

In my test I got this as soon as I refreshed the page after jamming lots of data into my page's cookies.

> ### Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
> Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
>
> `Cookie`

Here's the code I used to test it. It does exactly what you suggested, breaks the string up into chunks (after checking how much data the browser is able to stuff into a single cookie) and then inserts each chunk into an indexed cookie.

### This broke my test domain in Chrome, don't use this in production, for testing only.

```
var veryBigString = "Farts ".repeat(99999);
setCookieBatch('myBigCookie', veryBigString);

function setCookieBatch(cname, bigStr){
  var chunks = bigStr.match(new RegExp('[\\s\\S]{1,' +maxCookieSize() + '}', 'g'));
  for(var i=chunks.length; i--;){
    setCookie(cname+"_"+i, chunks[i]);
  }
}

function maxCookieSize(){
  for(var i=0;;i++){
    let str = "1".repeat(i);
    setCookie("c000test", str);
    if(getCookie('c000test') !== str){ 
      document.cookie = 'c000test=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
      return i;
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + 864000000000);
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
  }
  return "";
}
```

---

If you want a nice cross browser solution, consider [jSQL](https://github.com/Pamblam/jSQL);

Answer (score 1):

Don't store data in cookies.
Store data in a session using the session facade or session helpers.

If you need it to persist for a long time store a unique id in a cookie, and use that to retrieve data from relevant serialized file or database. Make sure to use a secure method to generate the ID and validate the ID, so some malicious user can't spoof cookie id's to iterate over it and get all the data of other users.